# Is an explicit export necessary when a function is made available from an index file?

Tags: javascript

I use vanilla JavaScript to define various components in separate folders. For example, the definition for the accordion component can be found in `accordion/accordion.js` and is structured as follows:

```js
import toggleCollapsible from "../../helpers/toggle-collapsible";

const SELECTOR_ACCORDION = ".accordion";
const SELECTOR_SLAT = ".accordion-slat";

function Accordion(accordion) {
...
}

Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(SELECTOR_ACCORDION)).forEach((accordion) => Accordion(accordion));

export default Accordion;
```

There is also an `index.js` file which is used only for making the component available elsewhere via `export * from "./accordion";`

Leaving out `export default Accordion;` part in `accordion.js` seems to work just fine. So is there any reason why I shouldn't drop it and simply use just `export * from "./accordion";` in the index file?

Comment: But you will have to use `import accordion from "path/to/accordion/accordion" ` instead of `import accordion from "path/to/accordion"`

Answer (score 1):

If you don't `export` anything from the module, then `export * from ...` will also export nothing.

However, just importing that module has that side effect of activating the array for elements on the page, which feels unclean (and indeed, might not work if the script is in `<head>`, for instance...).

I'd wrap the `Array.from()` stuff in a function that's exported:

```
export function activateAccordions() {
  Array.from(...);
}
```

and then import and call that in your `index`.

```
import {activateAccordions} from "./accordion";

activateAccordions(); // TODO: might need to call this only after the page is loaded
```

Then, if you additionally need to be able to accordion something arbitrary,

```
export function Accordion()
```

and import it too...

Comment: Forgot to mention all components are imported in a main file `import "./components/accordion"; ... import "./components/tabset";`
I then use esbuild to bundle all components in a single file which is deferred in HTML.

This yields the desired results even when using only `export * from ...` in index files.

I didn't run into any issues for not wrapping selector queries in a function, but as you mentioned doing it via a separate function seems like a cleaner solution.